# How can I have a multi-indexed torch Dataset?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have several timeseries that I want to classify with RNNs. I would like to have the get_item method take in either a dict or tuple, specifying both time idx and sequence idx. I have implemented that here.

```
class MLDataWrangler(zrfr.ZRFReader, torch.utils.data.Dataset):
   ...
   ...
  
  def __len__(self) -> int:
    # return len(self._all_flexions) # number of timeseries's
    return len(self._all_flexions), self._sequence_length # can I return multiple lengths?

  def __getitem__(self, idx) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, Dict[str, bool]]:
    if isinstance(idx, dict):
      frames = idx["frames"]
      sequence = idx["flexion"]
    elif hasattr(idx, "__iter__"):
      frames = idx[1]
      sequence = idx[0]
    

    zrf_path = self._all_flexions[sequence]
    video_pixels = self.read(zrf_path).data


    # signal level (input)
    if self._signame == SIGNAL_NAMES[1]:
      img_pixels = video_pixels.zsig[frames].astype(np.float32) # new since stacked
    elif self._signame == SIGNAL_NAMES[0]:
      img_pixels = video_pixels.rfsig[frames].astype(np.float32) # new since stacked


    # get finger ground truth
    labels = self._data_labels[sequence][1] # since stacked
    labels = np.array([labels[fing] for fing in FINGER_NAMES]).astype(np.float32) # convert dict to np array

    # transform as necessary
    if self.transform:
      img_pixels = self.transform(img_pixels)
    if self.target_transform:
      labels = self.target_transform(labels)
    return img_pixels.astype(np.float32), labels
```

My question is how do I use DataLoader on this? I assume I need a custom Sampler but I've tried searching and can't figure out what I need to implement.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: there's not a good way to do exactly this beceause python iterables are inherently 1D, but you can probably accomplish the same outcome with other approaches.

From docs, "Every `Sampler` subclass has to provide an `__iter__()` method". Now, your proposed dataset has two dimensions/indices, meaning you'd either need to flatten it (i.e. enumerate all possible time idx and sequence idx combinations and then map these to a 1-D iterable (list-like). That's probably how I'd recommend doing it. You could also select a random time_idx in `__getitem__` to eliminate the 2-D indexing. Exactly what you want to do will probably depend on how exactly you intend to train.

For example, here's the flattened enumeration of the 2D list implemented:

```
class MLDataWrangler(zrfr.ZRFReader, torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self,...):
        self.idx_map = []
        for i in range(len(self.all_flexions)):
            for j in range(len(self.all_flexions[i])):
                 self.idx_map.append([i,j])
        ...

    def __getitem(self,single_idx):
        idx = self.idx_map[single_idx]
        # now you can call idx[0], idx[1] as before
        ...
```

Comment: How can I split the dataset now for validation? I want to make use of sklearn's TimeSeriesSplit, but I'm not quite sure how to do that when the dataset is stacked like this.

Comment: Best practice is to keep a separate training and validation dataset and dataloader to prevent risk of bleedover. In terms of train-val split you have a few options. If you want full sequences to be held out for validation you can pre-separate the `i` range into 2 non-overlapping sets and pass this as input to each `MLDataWrangler` object. If you don't care about full sequences reserved, you can instead generate 2 random non-overlapping sets of indices spanning the length of `self.idx_map`, and use those to partition the data.